# How to set transparency to HUD Window

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder, hud

I am using standard HUD window (Drag and drop from IB Library). But I don't see any control to set the transparency of this HUD window.

I also tried to customize  NSPanel to create HUD window . But whatever the alpha value I set. It takes default alpha value. One more problem in this approach is I think I need to draw tittle bar.

Any solution or alternate solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://mattgemmell.com/source) has an example that subclasses NSPanel and draws an HUD Window completely from scratch. The background color/alpha can easily be changed from HUDWindow.m.

Comment: Yeah, but the licensing could be an issue. Also it was written in 2006.